# How can I validate a ajax form in codeigniter

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, validation

I want to validate a form using codeigniter form_validator library.

The problem is that the data comes from ajax, so I don't understand how the code should be.

```
    public function register(){
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $json = $_POST['data'];
    $json = json_decode($json);
    $data = get_object_vars($json);

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
    if($this->form_validation->run()){
        echo 'asdf';
    } else {
        echo 'xyz';
    }

}
```

You can see that there is a $data array similar with the $_POST superglobal array. How can I validate the $data array and send back a response with a json encoded array with status of form and errors messages?

This is the way of how I send data using ajax:

```
    function register(){
    var site_url = $("#site_url").val();
    var post_url = site_url+"index.php/ajax/register";

    var details = { };

    details.username = $("#username").val();
    details.password = $("#password").val();
    details.rpassword = $("#rpassword").val();
    details.country = $("#country").val();
    details.postal_code = $("#postal_code").val();
    details.email = $("#email").val();
    details.date_of_birth = $("#date_of_birth").val();


    var json = JSON.stringify(details);

    $.post(post_url, {'data': json}, function(data){
        alert(data);
        //data = JSON.parse(data);



    });

    return false;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: How are you sending the data from the view, can you show the AJAX call?

Comment: I've edited the first post. I've added the ajax code.

Comment: Why are you serializing the data and sending it as JSON? Why not just use POST fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay haven't tested this yet but it should work.

First off don't even bother sending the data to your controller as json, just send it as a normal post request.

```
$.post(post_url, {'data': details}, function(data){
```

Then in the controller you handle the validation just like you would any form validation.

```
public function register(){
$this->load->library('form_validation');
$this->form_validation->set_rules($this->input->post('username'), 'Username',
'trim|required|min_length[5]|max_length[12]|xss_clean');
if($this->form_validation->run()==FALSE){
    $errors = 'Username error here';
}
//You can iterate through any other validation rules building the $errors 
//variable then pass them back to the view with:

if(isset($errors))
{
    print json_encode(array("status"=>"error", "message"=>$errors));
} else {
   /execute pass code here
}

}
```

After that you can echo out the errors in the view, if there are any.

Comment: It doesn't work. I don't know how the $this->validaton_form object knows to look in the $_POST array for $_POST['username']. What is with  '$this->input->post['username]'' there? the code needed to be escaped to work.

Comment: That is how codeigniter handles the $_POST object. the first parameter of the validation is the thing you want to validate, the second parameter is the user friendly name you want to return to the user if there is an error and the third parameter is the things you want to check for. I also noticed there was a typo in the validation line. Try it now.

Comment: grrr, another typo. I use a custom input handler, round brackets on the $this->input->post not square.

Comment: It doesn't work. If you write var_dump($this->input->post('username')); it will return false. The code inside if brackets are executed everytime, no matter if the username is valid or not.

Comment: It's not posting to the form then. dump out the $_POST in the form to make sure the post variable is actually populating, and see edit to the if statement, lord I must have been tired when I wrote that. Sorry.

Comment: Thank you for helping me, the code still deosn't work. The $this->input->post('username') will return false because username in $_POST are something like this: $_POST['data']['username']; If I replace $this->input->post('username'); with $_POST['data']['username'] the problem are the same, there is error when the input is valid.

Answer (score 3):

From [the documentation](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/form_validation.html#rulereference):

> "Note: These rules can also be called as discrete functions. For example: $this->form_validation->required($string);".

Answer (score 0):

There is a way of validating data that are not from POST/GET requests.
I think this link should help: https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/form_validation.html#validating-an-array-other-than-post

I tested it on data that were from decoded `php://input`

```
$filters_obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
$this->form_validation->set_data($filters_prop_arr);
$this->form_validation->set_rules('email', 'Full Name', 'required');

if ($this->form_validation->run() == false) {
    var_dump('not workin');
    return false;
}
```